# Counting the number of days inbetween certain date range with **for loop**? (c++)

Tags: c++, for-loop

All the other questions i found were with different languages and were a bit too complicated for a beginner like me.

What is wrong with my code, that i cannot get the exact number of days inbetween my two input dates?

```
int getDate()
{
    std::cout << "Begins from: i.e 7th";
    int dateStart;
    std::cin >> dateStart;

    std::cout << "Ends: i.e 22nd";
    int dateStops;
    std::cin >> dateStops;

    int nrDays = dateStart;

    for(nrDays; nrDays < dateStops; nrDays++)
    {
    }

    return nrDays;
}
```

Is this possible using **for loop**?

I'm sorry for asking silly questions. I have just recently started to learn C++ and lots of things are still new to me.

Thank you for your answers! :)

p.s Also, if somebody wants to throw an idea on how to exclude weekends for example, it would be really nice. Although, my gut is telling me, that it will require a whole lotta more coding than what i have the capabilities to do yet.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The simple way, not excluding any, is `return dateStops - dateStart;`

Comment: Yes, forgot >> from std::cin in the post.. its in my code though. My goal is to get the exact number of days inbetween i.e 7th and 10th, which is 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a separate variable to count number of days .

try this one.

```
int getDate()
{
    std::cout << "Begins from: i.e 7th";
    int dateStart;
    std::cin >> dateStart;

    std::cout << "Ends: i.e 22nd";
    int dateStops;
    std::cin >> dateStops;

    int nrDays = dateStart;
    int daysCount=0;

    for(nrDays; nrDays < dateStops; nrDays++)
    {
           daysCount++;
    }

    return daysCount;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. And i have to say, i actually had my code setup this way in one point, but for some reason i didnt run it like that.. stupid me :) Thank you very much for this solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your loop is that you're assuming the iteration variable is a counter.  That turns out to be true in many loops, but here it isn't.  Your variable `nrDays` is not actually a number of days at all, but a date (it starts  at `dateStart` and goes to `dateStops`).  You really want something more like this:

```
int nrDays = 0;

for( int date = dateStart; date < dateStops; date++)
{
    if (isWeekday(date)) nrDays++;
}

return nrDays;
```

Note that you can't detect weekdays from just the day of the month.  You need to know what month and what year, or somehow else get the day of the week.

Comment: Ah, i see why i got it wrong now! Simple error and logic problems can make you feel incredibly stupid! p.s it seems that it would take whole lot more high level coding to implement some function that gives me dates from Windows calendar or such.. But i will get there in time :) Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your code shouldn't compile because of this line:

```
std::cin dateStart;
```

which should be:

```
std::cin >> dateStart;
```

A part from that, you loop is useless. What you apparently want is for `nrDays` to be equal to `dateStop - 1`:

```
int nrDays = dateStop - 1;
```

or more precisely:

```
int nrDays = std::max(dateStop - 1, dateStart);
```

which is: the maximum between `dateStart` and `dateStop - 1`.